# .Net NuGet package multi target .NetStandard 2.0 pre-release/.NetFramework v4.6.1 compatible to UWP project

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, .net-standard, .net-4.6.1

I've created a NuGet package that supports multi-target between .NetStandard 2.0 pre-release and .NetFramework v4.6.1 (built and used in Visual Studio 15.3 preview)

I know that the .NetStandard 2.0 pre-release is not compatible with UWP until vnext but it was my understanding that .NetFramework v4.6.1 was compatible.

I am currently unable to install my NuGet package to a UWP project, is there a way to make it compatible?

Comment: "but it was my understanding that .NetFramework v4.6.1 was compatible" - do you mean you expect to install a net461 package into UWP? I wouldn't expect that to work.

Comment: .NET Framework v4.6.1 is compatible with .NET Standard 2.0, not with UWP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [.NET Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/standard) is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are intended to be available on all .NET runtimes. It defines uniform set of APIs for all .NET platforms to implement, independent of workload.

When a NuGet package targets ***.NET Standard 2.0***, it means this package can be used both in ***.NET Core 2.0*** and ***.NET Framework 4.6.1*** (with tooling 2.0 preview). So literally, there is no multi-target between ***.Net Standard 2.0*** and ***.NET Framework 4.6.1***, it should be something like multi-target between ***.NET Core 2.0*** and ***.NET Framework 4.6.1***.

If you want your package to be compatible with **UWP** and **.NET Framework 4.6.1**, then you can target **.NET Standard 1.4**. This is the highest version of .NET Standard that both platforms support for now. So there is no way to install your .NET Standard 2.0 package to a UWP project.

> When choosing a .NET Standard version, you should consider this trade-off:
>
> - The higher the version, the more APIs are available to you.
> - The lower the version, the more platforms implement it.
>
> In general, we recommend you to target the *lowest* version of .NET Standard possible. So, after you find the highest .NET Standard version you can target, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Target the next lower version of .NET Standard and build your project.
> 2. If your project builds successfully, repeat step 1. Otherwise, retarget to the next higher version and that's the version you should use.

For more info, please see [.NET platforms support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-platforms-support).

And for **UWP** and **.NET Framework 4.6.1**, there is no compatibility between them. Although there is a subset of the types provided in the .NET Framework can be used to create UWP apps using C# or Visual Basic, but this is because these APIs are part of .NET Standard, so they are available in UWP. If a package is targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1, then it also can't be used in UWP.

Comment: What if you want someone who doesn't have VS2017 to consume this project? I mean I don't think VS2015 can understand reference to `standard2.0` project